# Specific texture wrap modes per-axis

Tags: uv, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

Some Nintendo games have certain texture wrap modes (or extentions in blender) per axis. Currently, Blender's 4 wrap options (Repeat, Clamp, Clip and Mirror) apply to both U and V axis. For example, If I want a texture with its U axis to be set to mirror, but its V axis to be set to repeat. How would I do that?

I've already tried crazy vector math operations on each axis to get the result I desire, however seams show up.

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what you are trying to achieve it's difficult to answer your question. Maybe you are looking for a setup like this?

[image: Shader Node Setup to Mirror U]

This setup separates the UV-vector and uses a **Math** node set to **Ping-Pong** to mirror the image on U while V is still repeating the texture infinitely. The second value of the Ping-Pong Math node can be used to shift the mirroring plane on U.

Comment: That's been my setup for the longest time but I still get seams. I don't know how hard it is to understand, per-axis wrap modes without seams. Most videogame engines have this functionality and so does opengl.

Comment: I guess, you need to elaborate on your specific problem because I don't get seems using this setup. One last thing that can reduce seams is setting the texture interpolation mode of the Image Texture node to "Closest".